# Connect to Gnome on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, gnome, vnc

I installed Ubuntu 16 on a VM.
Now I'd like to use it remotely with Gnome from Windows.
I followed every guide I found here and on the net about how to configure vncserver and the config files.
Nothing goes for me. At the most I can run a xfce session, but I'd like to have GDM or Gnome session.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Your desktop on Google Cloud Platform - VNC on Google Compute Engine instances](https://medium.com/google-cloud/linux-gui-on-the-google-cloud-platform-800719ab27c5#.4du84e219).

Comment: That was my starting point. No Results. Only the white/black "dotted" background of X.

Comment: https://almost-a-technocrat.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-start-up-vnc-session-with-gnome.html